# JAVA - Passing values between Classes

Tags: java

Given a login window which requires 2 inputs from the user: username & password.
After being identified successfully the user gets redirected to the main window.
Here I want to display his or her username but I'm receiving null.

This is my current code:
Login class:

```
private void LoginUser(String username, String password)
{
    user = username;
    pass = password;
    Connection conn = null;
    Statement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;

    try
    {
        conn = MainEngine.getConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT username FROM users WHERE username ='"+user+"' AND password ='"+getMD5Hex(pass)+"'");
        if(rs.next()) // Successful login
        {
            Window_AfterLogin window_afterlogin = new Window_AfterLogin();
            window_afterlogin.setVisible(true);
            this.dispose();
        }
        else
        {
            label_info.setText("Wrong credentials");
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}

public String getUserName()
{
    return user;
}
```

Note: user and pass variables are global.

Window_AfterLogin class:

```
public Window_AfterLogin() {
    initComponents();
    Window_Login window_login = new Window_Login();
    System.out.println(window_login.getUserName());
}
```

Comment: * Sorry for the unnecessary "in" word in the title

Comment: * you can edit your question and change the title...

Comment: where is main window code?

Comment: let main window be Window_Afterlogin

Comment: `new Window_AfterLogin("the user name")`. NB: You should read about usual naming conventions and SQL injection

Comment: show entire Window_AfterLogin  class in question please

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Window_AfterLogin()` constructor initializes another `Window_Login` which means there is the username, which you try to retrieve by `window_login.getUserName()` - `null`.

In your after login code you could add another field `username`:

```
public Window_AfterLogin{
   private String username;

   public Window_AfterLogin(String username){
          initComponents();
          this.username = username;
   }
}
```

Where inside your `LoginUser` class you have to change the code accordingly:

```
    if(rs.next()) // Successful login
    {
        Window_AfterLogin window_afterlogin = new Window_AfterLogin(user);
        window_afterlogin.setVisible(true);
        this.dispose();
    }
```

*Note*:

Your application is vulnerable to SQL-Injections. Please read about prepared statements and how SQL-Injections work in theory and try to prevent them.

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL-Injection
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/javaexamples/jdbc_prepared_statement.htm

Answer (score 0):

In the constructor, you are creating a new instance of the Window_Login class and not setting the username.